# Reuse a Fragment in a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I currently have a Fragment with some code and I want to be able to show this Fragment also in a Dialog, so I'm using a DialogFragment. Now how can I make sure it that I can just reuse the same Fragment without having to copy the code into the DialogFragment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make your `Fragment` extend `DialogFragment` instead. You can add it a layout normally as before, or call one of the [show](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show%28android.app.FragmentManager,%20java.lang.String%29) methods to show it as a dialog.

It you add it to a container, [DialogFragment.getShowsDialog()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#getShowsDialog%28%29) will return true. If you show it as a dialog, it will return false. Using this flag will allow you to, if required, write logic that can vary based on whether or not the Fragment is being shown as a dialog.

Comment: This seems to be the way to go, the only problem is that I've defined onClick-method in xml and when I'm displaying it as a Dialog I'm getting "Could not find a method myMethodName(View) in the activity", while it is defined in the activity...

Comment: @dumazy XML click listeners are not really compatible with a Fragment-based architecture (since they rely on click methods being handled by the Activity), so I would avoid using them. Views are owned/controlled by Fragments now so I think it is better to have all logic related to them within the containing Fragment, as opposed to the Activity. This is a matter of style, but I generally have Activities manage Fragments, and Fragments manage Views.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a CustomDialog where you override the `onCreateView()` method. A simple solution would be to add a `FrameLayout` to the layout of your `DialogFragment`.

Than you could init your `Fragment` in the `onCreateView()` and add this to your `DialogFragment` with a FragmentTansaction.